# Splitting and updating strings using dynamic SQL inside a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, cursor, dynamic-sql

The code below takes a single field that contains delimited text and splits it up and places it in adjacent fields depending on the amount of delimiters.

> Example of the delimited text: 
>   OFFR0048|OFFR0046|OFFR0044|OFFR0042|OFFR0040|OFFR0038|OF03993|

The code is running fine however it takes a considerable amount of time to complete.

Can this process below be executed more efficiently?

```
--create procedure variables
declare @CONS varchar(150), @SINGLE varchar(20), @BCC int, @SQLText nvarchar(1000), @Count int
--create cursor
declare String_Split CURSOR for
    select ADD_BARCODE from ADD_BARCODES --where (LEN(ADD_BARCODE) - LEN(REPLACE(ADD_BARCODE,'|',''))) >= 7 

open String_Split --open cursor

fetch next from String_Split INTO @CONS --set cursor to the first row

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 --start procedure
begin
  set @BCC = 1 --set the string field to 1
  while LEN(@cons) > 0 --start while there are addition codes to split
  begin
    if CHARINDEX('|',@CONS) > 0 --checks if there are strings to split
    begin --begin compound statement 1
      set @SINGLE = SUBSTRING(@cons,0,CHARINDEX('|',@CONS)) --use delimiter to split the string
      set @SQLText = 'update ADD_BARCODES set ADD_BC' + CAST(@BCC as varchar)+' = 
                      ''' + @SINGLE + ''' WHERE CURRENT OF String_Split' --create dynamic query to update relevant string column  
      exec sp_executesql @SQLText --execute dynamic query
      set @BCC = @BCC + 1 --increment string field with 1
      set @CONS = SUBSTRING(@CONS, LEN(@SINGLE + '|') + 1,len(@CONS)) --set the remaining string to the @cons varianble for further processing
    end --end compound statement 1
    else --if there are not strings to split
    begin --begin compound statement 2
      set @SINGLE = @CONS --set @cons variable equal to the @single variable
      set @CONS = null --execute dynamic query
      set @SQLText = 'update ADD_BARCODES set ADD_BC' + CAST(@BCC as varchar)+' = 
                      ''' + @SINGLE + ''' WHERE CURRENT OF String_Split' --create dynamic query to update relevant string column  
      exec sp_executesql @SQLText --execute dynamic query
    end --end compound statement 2
  end --end while there are addition codes to split
  fetch next from String_Split INTO @CONS --fetch next entry in cursor
end --end procedure

close String_Split --close cursor
deallocate String_Split --deallocate cursor memory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a parser function and then apply your updates in one statement with a join.  I suspect one update statement would be more efficient that constructing and executing 7 (in this case)

```
Declare @DelStr varchar(max) = 'OFFR0048|OFFR0046|OFFR0044|OFFR0042|OFFR0040|OFFR0038|OF03993|'

Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@DelStr,'|') Where Key_Value<>'' Order by 1
```

Returns

```
Key_PS  Key_Value
1       OFFR0048
2       OFFR0046
3       OFFR0044
4       OFFR0042
5       OFFR0040
6       OFFR0038
7       OF03993
```

There are millions of variations (some better/some worse), but here is my parser

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('id26,id46|id658,id967','|')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL , Key_Value varchar(max))

As

Begin
   Declare @intPos int,@SubStr varchar(max)
   Set @IntPos = CharIndex(@delimeter, @String)
   Set @String = Replace(@String,@delimeter+@delimeter,@delimeter)
   While @IntPos > 0
      Begin
         Set @SubStr = Substring(@String, 0, @IntPos)
         Insert into @ReturnTable (Key_Value) values (@SubStr)
         Set @String = Replace(@String, @SubStr + @delimeter, '')
         Set @IntPos = CharIndex(@delimeter, @String)
      End
   Insert into @ReturnTable (Key_Value) values (@String)
   Return 
End
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this, but it might be a lot faster:

1. Split the data into rows first, for example with [DelimitedSplit8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
2. Construct a pivot from the data. I would assume you have fixed number of columns in your table, so you can use fixed number of columns
3. Use the pivot for example in a CTE to update the data to the final table.